# MVVMCross 4.0 Xamarin Forms Page not Found

Tags: mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

We've been using MVVMCross for the 18 months.  Great Stuff.   But, we're looking to migrate from Xamarin.iOS to Xamarin.Forms in an effort to speed development time.

We have a PCL with our ViewModels.  But, would like to have our View (Pages) in a separate PCL library, to allow parallel development with Native application.

MVVMCross can not seem to locate the Page if it's located in a separate PCL library, OR if it's located in the Application.   However, if I put the Page in the same PCL as the ViewModels, things work like a champ.

I've tried putting the following code in our Setup.cs

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
    {
        var list = new List<Assembly>();
        list.AddRange(base.GetViewAssemblies());
        list.Add(typeof(NuSales.Forms.Pages.TestPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        return list;

    }
```

But, still no joy.

Any hints on how to fix the resolver to find the View (Page)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvxFormsPageLoader.cs#L44

```
    protected virtual Type GetPageType(string pageName)
    {
        return _request.ViewModelType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CreatableTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == pageName);
    }
```

... I'd say you need to override the default `IMvxFormsPageLoader` to change that single Assembly lookup.

...or (for **bonus** points) you could send in a Pull Request that changes the default behaviour to use the view assemblies collection - and it could also store a `Dictionary` to avoid multiple Reflection passes and to speed up lookup times.

Comment: That's Stuart, you are truly a ROCK STAR.   However, short of recompiling the assemblies, I see no easy way of overriding the FormPageLoader.   I attempt to send a Pull Request.   I say attempt, as I've never really done that before. :)

Comment: As long as you register your own `Iformpageloader` before https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvxPresenterHelpers.cs#L27 is called then your one will be used. (So register your one in setup... which is really where the Mvx one should be registered too...)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I'm doing this right in terms of StackOverflow etiquette.  Using Stuart's suggestion... A quick fix is.

Create a FormPageLoader like below.

```
public class MyFormsPageLoader : MvxFormsPageLoader
{
    public MyFormsPageLoader() {
    }

    protected override Type GetPageType(string pageName)
    {

        return typeof(NuSales.Forms.Pages.TestPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CreatableTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == pageName);
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it.  I did it in my App.Initialize code

```
public class FormsApp : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMvxFormsPageLoader), new MyFormsPageLoader());
        RegisterAppStart<TestViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can hook this into `Setup` somehow, then you can use `GetViewAssemblies()` to enumerate all the "view" assemblies... and I really would recommend you find the `CreatableTypes` just once - this uses reflection and you don't really want to add that overhead to every navigation.